# doctrine 2 join onetomany

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, mapping

If any doctrine expert if can help whit this:

there is a table, `[menu]`

which looks like

```
id | parent | lft | rgh | level | page_id
 1        0    1     2      0        1
```

there is a table `[pages]`

```
id | page_id | language_id | title |
 1      1       1            LANG1
 2      1       2            LANG2
```

so I would like to map this two tables with doctrine what I did so far is

in menu entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Page", mappedBy="page_id", fetch="LAZY")
 **/ 
private $pages;
```

and in the page entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entity\Menu", inversedBy="pages") 
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="page_id") 
 * }) 
 **/
private $page_id;
```

now all pages are store in arraycollection in Menu which is called $pages

Everything works fine, when I get

```
$repo = $em->getRepository('Entity\Menu');
$node = $repo->findOneById(1);

//this returns $pages var 
$page = $node->getPages()->toArray();
var_dump($page);
```

I can see that all pages related to selected node are there, but my goal is more to have, something as relation OneToOne I would like to have only one page related to the node by given language_id, but I don't know how to do it. I was wondering if there is a way to give the language_id with some where clause in the Page entity, but all my tries are without success so if someone can help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all day digging I found the way I don't know if is a good one but seems to work.

I created a method in my menu entity

```
public function getPageByLanguageId($language_id)
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create();
    $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('language', $language_id));

    return $this->pages->matching($criteria);
}
```

so I can get the page by language